# When switching to a new version of spring security, it is not possible to access the swagger ui

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, swagger-ui, spring-boot-actuator

I **use spring security**. I have set up a configuration file, and I can easily access the html template or the rest endpoint. However, there is either no access to the swagger-ui, or when I try to request, I get - '...not found'.

```java
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity httpSecurity) {

        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
                .formLogin(ServerHttpSecurity.FormLoginSpec::disable)
                .httpBasic(ServerHttpSecurity.HttpBasicSpec::disable)
                .authorizeExchange(authorizeExchangeSpec ->
                        authorizeExchangeSpec
                        
                                .pathMatchers( "/home").permitAll()
                                /*для endpoints*/
                                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/**").permitAll()
                                .pathMatchers(
                                        "/favicon.ico",
                                       "/v3/api-docs/**",
                                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                                        "/actuator/swagger-ui").permitAll()
                                .anyExchange().authenticated()

                )
                .build();
    }
}
```

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'

org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:1.7.0
org.springframework:spring-webflux:6.0.9

org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:6.1.0

implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-security:1.7.0'
```

application.yml

```yaml
CONTEXT_PATH_APP: /context-path

spring:
  webflux:
    base-path: ${CONTEXT_PATH_APP}


springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    path: /swagger-ui.html
  show-actuator: true
  use-management-port: true

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: openapi, swagger-ui
  server:
    port: 9090
```

http://localhost:9090/context-path/actuator/swagger-ui

http://localhost:8091/context-path/swagger-ui

[image]

http://localhost:8091/context-path/v3/api-docs

```yaml
{
  "status": 404,
  "message": "404 NOT_FOUND",
  "detailMessage": null
}
```

Share ideas on how to fix it and how to diagnose such errors?

Answer (score 1):

There is needed to use dependency (see https://springdoc.org/v2/#spring-webflux-support)

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui:2.1.0'
```

- application.yml

```yaml
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    enabled: true
```

```html
http://localhost:8091/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html

http://localhost:8091/v3/api-docs
```

- security

```java
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity httpSecurity) {

        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
                .formLogin(ServerHttpSecurity.FormLoginSpec::disable)
                .httpBasic(ServerHttpSecurity.HttpBasicSpec::disable)
                .authorizeExchange(authorizeExchangeSpec ->
                        authorizeExchangeSpec
                               .pathMatchers( "/home").permitAll()
                                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/**").permitAll()
                                .pathMatchers(
                                        "/favicon.ico",
                                       "/v3/api-docs/**",
                                        "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                                .anyExchange().authenticated()

                )
                .build();
    }
}
```

However, I also noticed that when deploying in a Kubernetes cluster, it is still impossible to access the swagger UI from the outside, even though security filters skip such requests (although locally it is possible) - to get a **404** error.

Try this:

```yaml
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    enabled: true
  swagger-ui:
    use-root-path: true
    config-url: /your_service/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
    url: /your_service/v3/api-docs
    disable-swagger-default-url: true
```